# Powershell parse unformatted text file

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am trying to parse a text file which is basically in a following format:

Name:   James

Location:   UK

I think it makes most sense to use Select-String:

```
$getName = "C:\account.txt"
Select-String -Path  $getName -Pattern 'Name:   '
```

However, this will return way more than I need. Can somebody please advise me how to get "James" and "UK" as different strings.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you having Name and location on same line or on different lines ?

Comment: Different lines

Comment: Did you consider using `"Get-Content" | Where-Object...` ? You want the content not the path or? Cause if you want to know in which file the string "James" is, then you would use `Select-String`

Comment: You are correct! It makes way more sense. I will try something, should you have any examples regarding my case it would be super helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this...

```
# Create user data sample and use regex match to get name and location only
Clear-Host
@'
Name: James
SomeOtherData: 
Location: UK
MoreStuff: 
'@ | Out-File -LiteralPath 'D:\Temp\account.txt'


Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\account.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {$PSItem | Select-String -Pattern '^(Name:\s|Location:\s).*'}
# Results
<#
Name: James
Location: UK
#>
```

Or this...

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\account.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {($PSItem | Select-String -Pattern '^(Name:\s|Location:\s).*') -replace '.*:\s'}
# Results
<#
James
UK
#>
```

There are a number of ways to do this. Meaning, list format as shown or table format.

Also, take a look at the [ConvertFrom-String cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1), to convert the strings to an object.

```
Clear-Host
$template = @'
{Property*:Name:} {Value:James}
{Property*:Location:} {Value:UK}
'@

$testText = @'
Name: James
SomeOtherData: 
Location: UK
MoreStuff: 
'@
```

I am using PowerShell variable squeezing to assign to the variable and output to the screen at the same time. 'This is not required.' It's just a shortcut to do two things at once when needed.

```
(
$PersonalData = $testText | 
ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
)
# Results
<#
Property  Value
--------  -----
Name:     James
Location: UK  
#>

$PersonalData.Property
# Results
<#
Name:
Location:
#>


$PersonalData.Value
# Results
<#
James
UK
#>

(
$PersonalData = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\account.txt'  | 
ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
)
# Results
<#
Property  Value
--------  -----
Name:     James
Location: UK  
#>
```

All the aforementioned are well documented, the PowerShell help files, MS Docs site, in blogs...

['PowerShell parsing text file'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20parsing%20text%20file%27&t=h_&ia=web) ...and videos on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27powershell%20parsing%20text%20file%27).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I can figure it out now.

Comment: No worries and unstructured date is always a pain.